# Unit test service with injected dependency using Angular 2

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm creating a simple unit test for a service that has a dependency. It is a simple service that I am starting on to help to get my head around the best process and structure.

The unit test I have created works but TypeScript throws an error.

```
Argument of type '{ order_id: string; user: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Expected<Observable<any>>'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'order_id' does not exist in type 'Expected<Observable<any>>'.
```

The service executes the method sendBody on the injected service which makes a HTTP post request. I understand an Observable should be returned here but I would have thought the mock service should have resolved this TypeScript type error.

Is there a better way to inject and mock dependencies when testing services only?

**Service**

```
export class ReturnOrderService {

    constructor(private _ReturnOrderResource: ReturnOrderResource) { }

    updateOrderStatus(orderId: string, user: string) {
        let body = {};

        if (orderId !== undefined && user !== undefined) {
            body["order_id"] = orderId;
            body["user"] = user;
        }

        return this._ReturnOrderResource.sendBody(body);
    }

}
```

**Spec**

```
const MockReturnOrderResource = {
sendBody: function(body) {
    return body;
  }
}

describe('ReturnsComponent', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({ providers: [
       ReturnOrderService,
       { provide: ReturnOrderResource, useValue: MockReturnOrderResource }
      ] });
  });

  it('#updateOrderStatus should create an object literal from arguments',
    async(inject([ReturnOrderService], (service: ReturnOrderService) => {
      expect(service.updateOrderStatus("10006886","Mr Bungle")).toEqual({ order_id: '10006886', user: 'Mr Bungle' });
  })));

});
```

Comment: what does `_ReturnOrderResource.sendBody` return? Can you add that code as well?

Comment: @sabithpocker it is passed through a few different services but essentially just makes a POST request using the Angular 2 Http class and Request method : https://angular.io/api/http/Http#request. So an Observable is expected to be returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked through a solution for this using a different approach. While it may not resolve the type error I was experiencing, it allows me to spyOn the injected service which is exactly what I was after.

After injecting the service I get the service using TestBed.get() and assign this to a variable.

I can then spyOn the injected service and test against the argument(s) the method was called with.

The updated spec below.

```
const MockReturnOrderResource = {
  sendBody: function(body) {
    return body;
  }
}

describe('ReturnsComponent', () => {
  let _ReturnOrderResource;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({ providers: [
       ReturnOrderService,
       { provide: ReturnOrderResource, useValue: MockReturnOrderResource }
      ] });
    _ReturnOrderResource = TestBed.get(ReturnOrderResource);
  });

  it('#updateOrderStatus should pass an object literal as an argument',
    async(inject([ReturnOrderService], (service: ReturnOrderService) => {
    spyOn(service, "updateOrderStatus").and.callThrough();
    spyOn(_ReturnOrderResource, "sendBody").and.callThrough();
    service.updateOrderStatus("10006886","Mr Bungle");
    expect(_ReturnOrderResource.sendBody).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ order_id: '10006886', user: 'Mr Bungle' })
  })));

});
```

For further reading around this solution: https://angular.io/guide/testing#testbedget

Answer (score 1):

If it must return an Observable, then return an Observable !

Try this :

```
const MockReturnOrderResource = {
    sendBody: (any: any) => Observable.of(any);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, trichetriche. I did try something similar (and now the above) but continued to get the same type error. All though the test itself passes in each case which is odd.

Comment: You error is that somewhere, you expected a parameter of type `Expected<Observable<any>>` but you provided a custom object. I suggest you find this error and you should be able to suppress this error.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I was able to find a solution using a different method to get the injected service and create a test against that. I've included the answer within this thread